# Create firebird database in specific directory

Tags: 12.04, permissions, mysql, database

I want to be able to create a firebird database in a specific directory. I know that the firebird user needs to have r/w/x permissions to the directory where I want to create the db. I created a group called 'tracker' and I added my user and the firebird user to that group.

```
firebird@ubuntu:/$ groups firebird
firebird tracker
```

I created a main directory called 'tracker'

```
drwxrwx---   3 me tracker  4096 Oct 16 10:40 tracker
```

Inside the 'tracker' directory I created an 'fdb' directory where I want the firebird DB's to be created.

```
drwxrwx--- 2 firebird firebird 4096 Oct 16 11:35 fdb
```

Now when I try to create the database using the following command:

```
CREATE DATABASE 'localhost:/tracker/fdb/test.fdb' page_size 8192 user 'SYSDBA' password 'foobar' DEFAULT CHARACTER SET UTF8;
```

I get the following error:

```
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 08001
I/O error during "open O_CREAT" operation for file "/tracker/fdb/test.fdb"
-Error while trying to create file
-Permission denied
```

If a change the 'tracker' directory to belong to the 'firebird' group then it creates the database, which makes sense, but since the firebird user belongs to the 'tracker' group, it shouldn't have any permission problems.

What am I missing here??

I'm using firebird 2.5.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try first with [firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/) user if you can create a file in that directory

> sudo su  firebird

also you might check DatabaseAccess in firebird.conf , but by default it should be Full

Comment: I did that and yes I can create a file in that directory. I will check DatabaseAccess. Thanks for the response.